# WebFroms How to refresh listbox in loop

Tags: c#, webforms, listbox, updatepanel

Is there way to update listbox in loop? I have an updatepanel with a listbox.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="updateButton" EventName="Click"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lbUpdatedCompanies" runat="server" Height="300px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="374px"></asp:ListBox>
        <br/>
        <asp:Button ID="updateButton" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateButtonClick" Text="Обновить"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <img src="../Icons/loading_spinner.gif" style="height: 60px; width: 65px" alt=""/>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

On button click I'm trying to add items to listbox in loop:

```
foreach (var company in companies)
{
    lbUpdatedCompanies.Items.Add(company.NAME);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

But the `listbox` shows changes after loop exit when all items are added

Comment: You want to add items to the list one at a time at one second intervals? I can't imagine a reason to do that... but it would be better accomplished with Javascript.

Comment: Haha. It's just a long operation.